# How to host multiple distinct web applications through a single domain, multiple URIs?

Tags: networking, webserver, synology

I have a series of separate application services I host on my home network (e.g. Plex). Some are hosted on separate physical machines on the same network. From outside of my network, I'd like to be able to host them all on the same port, port 80 for example. Right now, internal to my LAN, the sites are accessed like so:

- http://home.server1:8999
- http://home.server2:9500
- http://home.server2:10999

From outside, I'd like to host them like this (respectively)

- http://www.myhomeserver.com/service1
- http://www.myhomeserver.com/service2
- http://www.myhomeserver.com/service3

I do not run any linux machines, but I do have a Synology Diskstation. So I'd like, if possible, for my synology to act as the go-between to pull all these things together if possible. I'm not very familiar with web hosting, so I'm not sure where to begin here. What is the proper way to set this up, and does it require the applications themselves to be aware of this special URL setup when they probably expect to be hosted on dedicated ports?

Comment: @Ramhound documented where?

Comment: The keyword is "reverse proxy".

Answer (score 0):

> I have a series of separate application services I host on my home network (e.g. Plex). [...] From outside [of my network], I'd like to host them like this (respectively)
>
> http://www.myhomeserver.com/service1
> http://www.myhomeserver.com/service2
> http://www.myhomeserver.com/service3

As @grawity points out, the keyword is "reverse proxy". If an interface can be accessed with "http://", it should be eligible for proxying.

As a suggestion, I would look into [Apache](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) (possibly via [Apache Lounge](http://www.apachelounge.com) if you decide to use Windows) with [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html) enabled (and possibly some additional modules, such as [mod_proxy_html](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_html.html)). Your basic setup (if not using your NAS) will be using your router and a (semi-)dedicated computer to catch incoming web requests.

> I do not run any Linux machines, but I do have a Synology Diskstation. So I'd like, if possible, for my Synology to act as the go-between to pull all these things together[.]

You will have to look at the capabilities of your individual NAS model, since this may or may not be possible.

Particularly, many NAS devices uses [DLNA](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Living_Network_Alliance)-based network communication to serve media, which is not inherently compatible with what you propose (you would have to change your strategy to a [VPN](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) for anything DLNA-based e.g. [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net)). That said, if I am not mistaken, some NAS devices have the ability to deliver things via FTP, which *could* possibly be compatible with something like [mod_proxy_ftp](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_ftp.html). There also may be a web interface or other suitable web serving/proxying capabilities.

Note that this doesn't just apply your NAS. You need to investigate your services for their capabilities as well. For instance, Plex operates as a DLNA server by default. To proxy this setup as you suggest, you likely have to use the web interface (default port 32400).

> I'm not very familiar with web hosting, so I'm not sure where to begin here.

1. Get a domain of some kind and point it at your network. There plenty of tutorials on how to do this and (in theory) can be done for totally free.
2. Make sure your router is set up correctly (mostly port forwarding) and test your outside connection with a basic web server setup (again, there are a plenty of online tutorials).
3. Once you are certain you can contact your network from the outside using HTTP, set up a reverse proxy to your applications (and/or otherwise enable the correct NAS features for your model). Test and troubleshoot as necessary.

> [D]oes [proxying] require the applications themselves to be aware of this special URL setup when they probably expect to be hosted on dedicated ports?

There may be some special settings depending on your setup (e.g. Plex with SSL - not required) but for the most part, no extra knowledge on the part of the application should be required.